# In vue 3 I cant fix my components z-index

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, z-index

I have this Vue component,It's a basic dropdown.When I click on the button I get the dropdown but I get the list behind the other elements,I tried changing the z-index like a milion times and it still doesnt work

Template

```
 <template>
  <div class="select-wrapper" >
    <div class="select-button" @click="() => (toggleList = !toggleList)">
      <div class="select-button-text" :style="{ opacity: !!input ? 1 : 0.5 }">
        {{ dislaySelected() ?? "Select Option" }}
      </div>

      <div>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke-width="1.5"
          stroke="currentColor"
          style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"
        >
          <path
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if="toggleList" class="select-droplist">
      <input
        v-if="options.length > 2"
        v-model="searchQuery"
        class="search-option"
        placeholder="Search Options"
      />

      <div
        v-for="(option) in filteredOptions"
        :key="option.id"
        class="select-option"
        @click="() => selectOption(option)"
      >
        <div  :class="{ 'selected-option': isSelected(option) }">
          {{ option.name }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref, onMounted, } from "vue";
interface SelectOption {
  id: string | number;
  name: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
  options: { id: string | number; name: string }[];
  returnType?: keyof SelectOption;
  modelValue?: string | number;
}>(), {
  returnType: 'id'
});

const emits = defineEmits<{
  "update:modelValue": [value: string | number];
}>();

const input = computed({
  get: () => props.modelValue,
  set: (value) => emits("update:modelValue", value),
});

const toggleList = ref<boolean>(false);
const searchQuery = ref<string>("");
const filteredOptions = computed(() =>
  props.options?.filter((option) => option.name.match(searchQuery.value))
);

function selectOption(option: SelectOption) {
  if (input.value === option[props.returnType]) {
    input.value = null;
  } else {
    input.value = option[props.returnType];
    toggleList.value = false;
  }
}

function isSelected(option: SelectOption) {
  return input.value === option[props.returnType];
}

function dislaySelected() {
  return props.options?.find((option) => option[props.returnType] === input.value)?.name
}

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
});

function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent) {
  const target = event.target as Element;
  if (!target.closest(".select-wrapper")) {
    toggleList.value = false;
  }
}

</script>
```

and the style is in another file called main.css

```
body{
    width: 100%;
}

.select-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
  
.select-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 46px;
    place-items: center;
    padding-left: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-button-text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.selected-option {
color: blue;
font-weight: bold;
}

.select-droplist {
width: 100%;
max-height: 300px;
background-color: white;
border: none;
border: 1px solid lightgray;
border-radius: 4px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
overflow-y: auto;
z-index: 1000;
}

.search-option {
width: 100%;
height: 46px;
padding: 0px 16px;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0 0 0 / 0.05) !important;
outline: none;
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
background-color: white;
}

.select-option {
width: 100%;
height: 46px;
display: flex !important;
align-items: center;
padding: 0px 16px;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0 0 0 / 0.05);
}

.select-option:hover {
background-color: rgba(0 0 0 / 0.05);
}

.select-option:nth-last-child(1) {
border-bottom: none;
}
```

I am using bootstrap but I don't think that would be the problem,
Also I use the component in a virtual scroller,here's how it looks

```
 <RecycleScroller
        class="scroller"
        page-mode
        :items="store.clinicData.value[store.activeTabKey.value]"
        v-slot="{ item, index }"
        key-field="name"
        :item-size="80"
      >
      <div class="user">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm">
                {{ item.speciesName }}
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm text-truncate">
                {{ item.name }}
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm">
             <Selector  :options="mapBreeds(item.chqSpeciesId)" v-model="item.chqId" :key="item.index" />
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.isMixed" />
                <strong>Is Mixed</strong>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </RecycleScroller>
```

and here are the styles for the scroller,even tho I think that they are not the problem

```
    .scroller {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.user {
  height: 32%;
  padding: 0 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```